# calculus 1 dy/dx? $y=(\ln x)^{\ln x} , x>1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Use logarithmic differentiation to find dy/dx

$y=(\ln x)^{\ln x} , x>1$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Do you mean $\ln x$, so $(\ln x)^{\ln x}$?

Comment: yes, that what i mean  @amWhy

Comment: do you know what logarithmic differentiation is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let u = $ln(x)$. Therefore,
$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$
let the following equation be eqn (1).
$$ y = [ln(x)]^{ln(x)} $$

substituting u into eqn(1) and taking the natural log on both sides,
$$ ln(y) = uln(u) $$

differentiate both sides with respect to u

$$ \frac{1}{y}(\frac{dy}{du})=ln(u)+1 $$

taking $\frac{dy}{du}.\frac{du}{dx}$ we have:

$$ \frac{dy}{du}.\frac{du}{dx} = y[ln(u)+1](\frac{1}{x}) $$

substituting u for x
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(lnx)^{lnx}}{x}[ln(lnx)+1] $$

for x>1:

[image: graph of dy/dx]

we see that $\frac{dy}{dx} < 0 $ for $ 1 \lt x \leq 1.4446679 $ and $ \frac{dy}{dx} \geq 0 $ for $ x \geq 1.4446679 $

Answer (score 0):

$y=(\ln x)^{\ln x}.$ Taking $\ln$ on both the sides we get $\ln y=\ln ((\ln x)^{\ln x})$ which is nothing but
$\ln y=\ln x \ln (\ln x)$ Differentiate w. r. t. x.
$(1/y) dy/dx= \ln x .(1/(x\ln x))+(1/x) \ln(\ln x).$ Now simplify and complete to write the expression for $dy/dx.$